# How to organize work between 2 git repos?

Tags: git, github

We have a setup where we internally use git to do our work and at the same time the client we deliver the work to also uses git on their own.

We also want to have a strict border between 2 repos so that client is not involved into our repo workflow (internal issues, users, PR policies, etc) nor we want to be involved into their.

We are considering workfow like this:

1. Our devs do all their work against `our-repo` in `development` branch (set as default)
2. Our repo admin has access to `client-repo` (meaning he has 2 remotes: `our-repo` and `clients-repo`)
3. Once something is ready to deploy (meaning, is pushed to our `master` branch) he gets it and push it to `clients-repo`
4. In case client themselves do some changes (rare but possible), our admin gets it and merge to `our-repo`

Would this setup work? Am i missing anything important?
Are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

I think that having two separate repos which both contain logically the same (or at least very similar) code is unnecessary, and a generally bad idea.  I suggest that you just maintain a single repo.  Make the `master` branch (and possibly other branches) protected in GitHub.  You may read [Enabling branch restrictions](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/) for more information on how to do that.

When your clients want to do their own work, simply let them create a new feature branch.  If they want, they may create a pull request back to `master`, which you and your internal team can carefully review, before merging.  Since `master` would not be protected, your client would never have the direct ability to alter the codebase.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I agree having the same thing in 2 repos is odd but on the other hand, things other than branches themselves are a source of this way of thinking: we dont want client to see our devs, issues (nor we want to see theirs), labels, project management part, we dont want their ci/cd connected to our repo, etc... is it possible to restrict all of that and just allow them to push to `client-push` branch and pull `master`?

Comment: @deezg Yes, I think you can configure GitHub to hide most of this information from your client users.  Having two separate repos introduces a huge overhead, which doesn't really serve much purpose other than this.

Comment: hm...i wasnt aware you could setup all of these other things. is there maybe a single link/guide how to do it?

Comment: Check the GitHub documentation.  I have provided one such link in my answer.

Comment: ok, let me check and i'll get back here quickly to accept answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see github.com's permission matrix at https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/

Your wish can not be reality, if our team and our client use github.com in same time (let see matrix at row `Open issues`, pull, etc.)

**I have an idea**

- Our team use github.com service
- Our client use a **git mirror repository** (not on github.com) https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

Therefore, our client cannot see pull request process, issue, issue discussion, etc. they only see source code what our team deliver to them.

Comment: yes, thats what i was afraid of: permission matrix not allowing such combination. mirroring repo sounds promising. looking into that. thanks!